# Do Item custom properties share the same limitations as extended properties?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office-js

The documentation mentions that extended properties are a finite resource in a user's mailbox, and exceeding this limit will result in unexpected errors when trying to create new properties.

It is not mentioned explicitly anywhere that I could if item customProperties, as written to through the Office.js client, has the same limitation. Does it?

We plan to optionally write a small amount of data to item customProperties if the user modifies inputs exposed in our Add-in Taskpane in the Outlook client. These properties will later be read by a server consuming changed events through the events delta API.

Will we eventually run into issues with this approach if we don't implement some sort of "garbage collection" of no longer used customProperties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Item custom Properties are extended properties https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxcext/4cf1da5e-c68e-433e-a97e-c45625483481?redirectedfrom=MSDN

So you have one extended property and then the value is a Json Key pair so one Extended property provides multiple custom properties (up to the limitation of the size of the Extended property)

Even if you don't want to use Item Custom properties its a good idea to follow the same approach eg create one extended property for your app and then store what ever combination of property values you need as a JSON structure in the value on the property. Its not a good idea to have your application creating random/multiple custom properties as you will easily exhaust them/create a mess and there is no advantage in doing it that way.

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, [custom properties as mentioned in the Office.js documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.customproperties?view=outlook-js-preview) are represented as a single [named property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxcext/1c054075-bb9b-4c10-b596-20cec57a9b76#gt_e6245def-e67d-4ab2-8c7d-04863b1c1063) on the Message object.

Comment: Never caught the limit of 2500 bytes before, that's good to know. Assuming we stay under that limit for each Message's customProperties, should we be concerned about cleaning up the customProperties on old Messages, that is the part the documentation is really unclear about.

Comment: Most Outlook addin's don't as its generally only a same amount of data and most dev's aren't really concerned about the storage of that (just check the amount of properties on an items using a MAPI editor) and the cleanup would need to be done generally outside of the addin.

Comment: Marking this as the accepted answer, though it's still unclear to me if our add-in will one day cause memory issues (sounds like the answer is "probably ‍♀️"). Huge kudos to pointing me to a MAPI editor, that helped me do some digging and discover some useful properties for our application, nice